# Readability of Heap profile graphs

Tags: haskell

I want to demonstrate that the heap profile of my application roughly stays the same over time. Albeit, that there are no space leaks that build up over time. The graphical heap profile that I get with hp2ps is fine and readable if I let the application run for a couple of seconds, but it becomes a complete mess if I let the application run for half an hour or longer. What do I do to increase readability? Can I reduce the sample density or else?

[image: heap profile]

Comment: @NathanHowell Is the same effect.

Comment: Ok... well you can edit the .hp file (it's just a text file) and remove older data, sample or aggregate it. I don't know if there are any existing tools that would help though.

Comment: @NathanHowell Is there not just an option to lift of the black border lines that hp2ps paints around the bands? I feel that this may be a help already.

Comment: No idea... I've never dug through the code and don't recall any --help output for hp2ps or hp2pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the sampling interval with the '-in' option to RTS, e.g. '-i10' to sample every 10s instead of the default 0.1s. See the [GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/prof-heap.html#rts-options-heap-prof) for more info.

Alternatively you can change the orientation and size of hp2ps output or change the number of displayed bands (see 'hp2ps -?'), though it's hard to say if this will help you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise to use [ekg](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ekg/) and sample the heap usage via JSON with any frequency you wish. You can then plot your data with gnuplot or R.

An additional benefit of this approach is that you don't need a profiling build, so your data will be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing wrong with the figure -- yes, it's "untidy", whatever that means, but it also shows that there's no runaway curve.